# Adding buffer from calculated value?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, buffer

[image]

So I have a script that calculates a diameter of a crater of an asteroid with user input parameters. what i need help with is creating a buffer that brings in the diameter as the distance value and creates a buffer around different point locations. I can't seem to find a way to bring the value into the buffer tool. I have also tried to find a way to just add the distance to layer i want to do a buffer around as an attribute.

```
def main():
    import arcpy
    velocity = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
    mass = arcpy.GetParameter(1)
    component = GetParameterAsText(2)

    dct_mat = {'ice' : 1.8, 'iron' : 7.3, 'rock' : 2.3}
    comp = dct_mat[component]
    grav = (0.16667)
    const = (0.007)
    colrt = (1.3)
    soil = (2.65)
    power = (1.0/3.4)
    vel = (velocity * 1000.0)
    kilotons = (4184000000000.0)
    kinetic = (0.5 * mass * (vel ** 2))
    energy = (kinetic * kilotons)
    part1 = (const * colrt * grav)
    part2 = (comp / soil)
    part3 = (energy * part2)
    part4 = (part3 ** power)
    crater = (part1 * part4)
    final = (crater / int(1000))

    arcpy.SetParameter(3, final)
    arcpy.AddMessage("final: {}".format(final))


if __name__ == '_main_':
    main()
```

here is the script i'm using. also i cant get the message to work but that isn't as important right now.

Comment: Is it buffer or multiple ring buffer. The buffer tool has 'buffer field or value', just add a field, populate with the crater distance and put in the field name and the linear unit is used from there (must be numeric and in the units of the spatial reference of the data). Can you include some of this script for us to see what you're up to and where you're stuck.

Comment: the script i'm using outputs a long value but the buffer tool only allows you to input a table of points lines or polygons to create a buffer around and the field input only accepts field from that table

Comment: From a question I answered yesterday, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261861/passing-file-from-python-script-to-modelbuilder-tool/261873?noredirect=1#comment415113_261873 your SetParameter may be incorrect. Where are you implementing buffer http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000? The 3rd parameter is buffer_distance_or_field, assuming your 'final' value is in metres '{} meters'.format(final) should work (meters is American spelling, the British/Australian spelling doesn't work). If you're using later SetParameterAsText(2,'{} meters'.format(final))

Comment: And in your script tool define the output parameters' type as 'linear unit' so it can be ingested by the buffer tool, or do the buffer in this tool just after the AddMessage line; of course you'd need to add another input parameter to specify the buffer location/name.

Comment: how would i define my output parameter as a linear unit?

Comment: In the script tools' properties http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000n000000 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/01m1/pdf/Geoprocessing_data_types.pdf (page 3 of 6). If it's not the right data type the buffer tool will not allow you to put the output parameter into its input parameter. This is one reason why it's easier to do the buffer inside the existing script rather than to have the buffer as a new process.

Comment: ok so i tried to add the buffer to the end of my script like you suggested but with my limited arcpy experience i cant seem to figure this out

Comment: You'll also need to change your if statement to read `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Note the double underscore as opposed to single underscore in your code. Main won't run, which could explain things.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the buffer into the script is fairly easy:

```
import arcpy,os
velocity = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
mass = arcpy.GetParameter(1)
component = GetParameterAsText(2)
ImpactLoc = GetParameterAsText(3) # add this input parameter to the script tool

dct_mat = {'ice' : 1.8, 'iron' : 7.3, 'rock' : 2.3}
comp = dct_mat[component]
grav = (0.16667)
const = (0.007)
colrt = (1.3)
soil = (2.65)
power = (1.0/3.4)
vel = (velocity * 1000.0)
kilotons = (4184000000000.0)
kinetic = (0.5 * mass * (vel ** 2))
energy = (kinetic * kilotons)
part1 = (const * colrt * grav)
part2 = (comp / soil)
part3 = (energy * part2)
part4 = (part3 ** power)
crater = (part1 * part4)
final = (crater / int(1000))

arcpy.AddMessage("final: {}".format(final))
ILname, ILext = os.path.splitext(ImpactLoc) # break up the impact location to "name" and ".ext"
BufferName    = ILname + '_Buffer' + ILext  # name as impact location with _buffer in the name

# perform the buffer
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(ImpactLoc,BufferName,'{} meters'.format(final)) # change the 'meters' to 'feet', 'kilometers' etc if your final units are different

# set the buffer as output, perhaps SetParameterAsText might be more suitable
arcpy.SetParameter(4, BufferName)           # Change this output parameter to feature class
```

But you need to make some changes to the script tool used in the model, add a parameter of type feature class for your impact locations then move your output down one line and change the type also to feature class in order for the tool to work in model builder.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\Courses\304\bbrewe1\Asteroid_project\ie with buff.py", line 30, in <module>
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(impactloc,BufferName,'{} kilometers'.format(final)) # change the 'meters' to 'feet', 'kilometers' etc if your final units are different
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 692, in Buffer
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Input Features: Value is required
Failed to execute (Buffer). i got this error when i tried to run the script

Comment: Have you modified the script tool properties (in its toolbox) to add the new parameter and have you populated the new parameter with your Impact Locations.shp ? It's telling you that the buffer 'from' features isn't populated.

Comment: I believe that I have but I will take a look again. I know I added the new parameter; I am guessing that the problem is the population of the feature.

Comment: so i cant seem to get ILname, ILext to popuate

Comment: What is the value of ImpactLoc? Have you imported os?